# force base class to use its own method and not overrided method

Tags: java, inheritance

here is my scenario:

```
class SomeBaseClass
{
     public void foo(String str)
     {
     .......
     }
     public void foo(String strs[])
     {
     .......
     }
}

class MyClass extends SomeBaseClass
{
     public void foo(String str)
     {
           super.foo(str);
     }
     public void foo(String strs[])
     {
           throw new RuntimeException("only one input please!");
     }
}
```

The logic is pretty simple. "SomeBaseClass" is 3rd party tool that i cannot modify. I want to limit its functionality and don't want to allow foo(String strs[]).

the problem is that inside SomeBaseClass foo(Sting str) internally calls foo(String strs[]). Hence when i call foo(String str) of MyClass, I get a runtime exception. How can I tell the SomeBaseClassclass to use SomeBaseClass::foo(String strs[]) and all other classes to use MyClass ::foo(String strs[])

Comment: Wild guess, have you tried `this.foo()`? (I don't know Java that well, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps over engg but inside `MyClass.foo(String strs[])` you can check if the caller is `SomeBaseClass.foo(String str)`, if yes, let the call go thru to `super.foo(String)` else `throw RuntimeException`.

To find the caller check `StackTrace`.

Comment: Using stack trace may decrease performance significantly, though there's another way to determine whether to call super or throw an error. In `foo (String)` you can mark that super call is allowed (using local class variable if thread-safety isn't required or using ThreadLocal otherwise) and check the flag in `foo (String[])`. But wrapper is a better practice and in case of thread-safety will surely work faster.

Comment: Good point (abt the flag), guess it's the best option, (you should add it). It's also possible to make it thread safe of course (with a little effort). I do agree abt the performance hit otherwise, but I took it that its implicit/clear.

Comment: both stacktrace and using flag worked. thanks Kashyap.
I preferred using stack trace.

Comment: Great! Do note that even in my opinion Andrei's soln is better than mine. **I mean the one with teh flag**. But whatever sails ur boat. :)

Comment: @kashyap: i do agree its useful for some cases. but it my case the architecture is multi-multi threaded. i cannot risk thread-safety.

Answer (score 5):

Consider writing a wrapper

```
class MyClass extends SomeBaseClass
{
    private SomeBaseClass impl = new SomeBaseClass ();

    public void foo(String str)
    {
        impl.foo(str);
    }

    public void foo(String strs[])
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("only one input please!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it ought to be pointed out that *every single method* inherited from `SomeBaseClass` will have to be forwarded to `impl`, and if `SomeBaseClass`'s vendor decides to quietly add a new member function in a new version, this'll quietly break.

Comment: Am I missing something here? `MyClass` still `extends SomeBaseClass`, so how exactly is it this stopped: `MyClass.foo(String)`->`SomeBaseClass.foog(String)`->`MyClass.foo(String[])`->`throw ...`. Got it. :)

Comment: Here `impl.foo(str)` impl is an instance of `SomeBaseClass` so it will not lead to `MyClass.foo (String[])`.

Comment: in my original implementation, SomeBaseClass has like 100's of methods and properties. its completely bad practice to make such an implementation as there will a lot of maintenance / up-gradation issues.